# Exoplayer can't load subtitles of HLS video

Tags: android, exoplayer

Here is my m3u8 with subtitles embedded:

```
#EXTM3U


#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="Vietnamses",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,FORCED=NO,LANGUAGE="vi",CHARACTERISTICS="public.accessibility.transcribes-spoken-dialog, public.accessibility.describes-music-and-sound",URI="http://api.mhdviet.vn/sub.m3u8?language=VIE&movieid=8220&ep=1"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="Vietnamses (FORCED)",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,FORCED=YES,LANGUAGE="vi",URI="http://api.mhdviet.vn/sub.m3u8?language=VIE&movieid=8220&ep=1"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="English",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,FORCED=NO,LANGUAGE="eng",CHARACTERISTICS="public.accessibility.transcribes-spoken-dialog, public.accessibility.describes-music-and-sound",URI="http://api.mhdviet.vn/sub.m3u8?language=ENG&movieid=8220&ep=1"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="English (FORCED)",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,FORCED=YES,LANGUAGE="eng",URI="http://api.mhdviet.vn/sub.m3u8?language=ENG&movieid=8220&ep=1"

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=855040,RESOLUTION=480x352,SUBTITLES="subs"
http://allvarhsin.flix-cdn.com/FlixVOD/ACompany/I_Frankenstein_2014/1f9daf14d2f84cd8cd0121804ec1e35a/480/480.m3u8
```

I used `Exoplayer` to load my hls video. **What is wrong with my m3u8 file?**

Answer (score 1):

In ExoPlayer 1.5, your master manifest is parsed, the 4 languages are added to the collection. The result is a valid HlsMasterPlaylist.
Video Playback also starts correctly.

If I comment out the subtitles member (and its initialization) in HlsMasterPlaylist class the code still compiles and runs the same way.

```
public final class HlsMasterPlaylist extends HlsPlaylist {
    public final List<Variant> variants;
    //public final List<Subtitle> subtitles;
```

**It seems that your manifest is parsed correctly, but the linked subtitles are not used** (that part is not implemented yet).